# NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python

hi i am so sorry for the long code but i will try to cut some of it 
if want to ask the user to  put the target ip and then choose from the menu :) the functions work fine but the question and the next step i dident khnow how to do :/ sorry for my bad english

```
menuu = """
  1) Get all websites
  2) Get joomla websites
  3) Get wordpress websites
  4) Find control panel
  5) Find zip files
  6) Find upload files
  7) Get server users
  8) Scan from SQL injection
   9) Crawl and scan from SQL injection
   10) Scan ports (range of ports)
   11) Scan ports (common ports  )
   12) Get server banner
   13) Bypass Cloudflare
   99) Exit
  """
  def unique(seq):
      """
get unique from list found it on stackoverflow
"""
seen = set()
return [seen.add(x) or x for x in seq if x not in seen]

  def clearScr() :
"""
clear the screen in case of GNU/Linux or 
windows 
"""
if system() == 'Linux':
    os.system('clear')
if system() == 'Windows':
    os.system('cls')

  class TNscan :
def __init__(self, serverip) :
    self.serverip = serverip
    self.getSites(False)
    print menuu
    while True :
        choice = raw_input(' Enter choice -> ')
        if choice == '1' :
            self.getSites(True)
        elif choice == '2' :
            self.getJoomla()
        elif choice == '3' :
            self.getWordpress()
        elif choice == '4' :
            self.findPanels()
        elif choice == '5' :
            self.findZip()
        elif choice == '6' :
            self.findUp()
        elif choice == '7' :
            self.getUsers()
        elif choice == '8' :
            self.grabSqli()
        elif choice == '9' :
            nbpages = int(raw_input(' Enter number of pages to crawl               (ex : 100) -> '))
            self.crawlSqli(nbpages)
        elif choice == '10' :
            ran = raw_input(' Enter range of ports, (ex : 1-1000) -> ')
            self.portScanner(1, ran)
        elif choice == '11' :
            self.portScanner(2, None)
        elif choice == '12' :
            self.getServerBanner()
        elif choice == '13' :
            self.cloudflareBypasser()
        elif choice == '99' :
            print ' Goodbye'
            exit()
        con = raw_input(' Continue [Y/n] -> ')
        if con[0].upper() == 'N' :
            exit()
        else :
            clearScr()
            print menuu
```

and here i cuted a lot of funtions , then ,

```
def tnn():

    clearScr()
    aaa = raw_input("Target IP : ")
    aaa = self.serverip
    TNscan()
```

here is where i dident khnow what to do

Comment: your indentation is messed up; it looks like `tnn` is supposed to be a class method, ie should be `tnn(self)` where `self` is an automatically inserted reference to the object it is called on, ie `a.tnn(b, c)` calls `tnn(a, b, c)`.

Comment: so how do i fix my script , i dident understand you , i am a new python programmer :(

Comment: Grab a fresh copy - https://github.com/voletri/TNscan/blob/master/tnscan.py - and don't mess up the indentation.

Comment: ... also be aware it's very hacky, not a good example for learning to program.

Comment: @HughBothwell i want to add it into my script so please any solutions ? if you want i can send you the full file and you check it out

Answer (score 1):

Found It Out Thanks to @pythontips

```
class tnn():
    def __init__(self):
        clearScr()
        aaa = raw_input("Target IP : ")
        TNscan(aaa)
```